# How to change timestamp formate in csv file in linux

Tags: linux, bash, csv, timestamp

I have few miilion records in a csv file. Which has timestamp with this formate `2007-12-15T00:00:00.000Z`. I have to convert it into `2007-12-15 00:00:00` format. Each record contains 2 timestamps field. Please help me in doing this.

This is a sample record from my csv file

```
 ObjectID(5334cb)," UK TEAM","292","P 4LR",0,2007-12-15T00:00:00.000Z,2007-12-15T00:00:00.000Z,34.98,170,"Chatt 14/12/2007",22.7,4.5,"Shipped",5.20,1
```

Comment: There are numerous such examples around.  Make a _minimal effort_ to search.

Answer (score 0):

Strip the trailing "Z" and ensure your local time zone is zulu (UTC) and:

```
$ date -d '2007-12-15T00:00:00.000'
Fri Dec 14 09:00:00 PST 2007
```

naturally, you need to fiddle the date format to suit your needs

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple string manipulation.

```
perl -i -pe 's/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})T(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\.\d{3}Z/"$1 $2"/g' file.csv
```

Just remember, when you subsequently process the file, the timestamps are in UTC timezone.